# jQuery pausing a timer on mouseenter and mouseout not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this auto changing of images which works but tying to add so it pauses on hover and resets when leave element but it continues to scroll through and does not pause. I'm new to JS and jQuery.

JS

```
var galleryTimer;
var galleryTimeOut = "2500";
  var galleryImage = ".productImage";

  // auto play function to go through images
  function galleryPlay() {
    $(galleryImage).each(function(index) {
      var self = this
      galleryTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.productImage').removeClass('active');
        $(self).addClass('active');
      }, index * galleryTimeOut);
    });
  }

  // pause when hovering main image and zooming image
  function galleryPause() {
    clearTimeout(galleryTimer);
  }

  // next function to move to next image
  function galleryNext() {

  }

  // prev function to move back to prevous image
  function galleryPrev() {

  }

  $(galleryImage).mouseenter(function() {              
    galleryPause();        
  }).mouseleave(function () {     
    galleryPlay();
  });

  $('.galleryNext').on('click', function(event){

  });

  $('.galleryPrev').on('click', function(event){

  });

  // auto start the auto play
  galleryPlay();
```

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li class="productImage active">
    <a><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="productImage">
    <a><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"></a>
  </li>
  <li class="productImage">
    <a><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"></a>
  </li>
    <li class="productImage">
    <a><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"></a>
  </li>
    <li class="productImage">
    <a><img src="http://placehold.it/350x350"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
<a class="galleryNext">next</a>
<a class="galleryPrev">next</a>
```

Comment: because you overwrite galleryTimer on every iteration so you have multiple timers but you only every have the last timer to cancel.

Comment: I think  get what you mean, im really new to js / jquery so this is kind of my first attempt at something like this...what would you suggest? and thanks for your time!

Comment: Use one timer and on each iteration you show the nextSibling

Comment: Sorry to ask but would you mind providing an example as im totally lot with it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have this

```
var galleryTime;
galleryTime = 1;
galleryTime = 2;
galleryTime = 3;
```

And you are expecting that variable to have all 3 values. That is not the case. Each iteration overrides the previous.

You need one timer and not have multiple. This is the basic idea.

```js
$( function() {
  var timer;
      lis = $(".img");
  
  function showNext() {    
    var active = lis.filter(".active").removeClass("active");
    var next = active.next();
    if (next.length===0) {
        next = lis.eq(0);  
    }
    next.addClass("active");    
  }

  function playGallery() {
    stopGallery();
    timer = window.setInterval(showNext, 1000);
  }

  function stopGallery() { 
    if (timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);
  }
  
  $(".gallery")
    .on("mouseleave", playGallery)
    .on("mouseenter", stopGallery);

  playGallery();
  
});
```

```css
.img {
    display : none;  
}

.img.active {
    display: block;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="gallery">
  <li class="img active">1</li>
  <li class="img">2</li>
  <li class="img">3</li>
  <li class="img">4</li>
  <li class="img">5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: How can  add the hover to pause on that? sorry to be a pain? would be awesome if we could do a next and prev button s well